# Can eggs boil indefinitely?

Tags: boiling-point

At breakfast someone asked if the eggs were boiling. While obviously they meant the water for the eggs, but it lead to a discussion regarding if you can make an egg boil without it coagulating or even if you can heat a coagulated egg to the point that it starts boiling under special circumstances such as in an oxygen free environment to prevent combustion.

So would it be possible to make an egg boil without coagulation or otherwise destroying it? The shell would break either way so we can remove that for the experiment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boiling means dynamic evaporation of liquid.

Infinite boiling would mean to have infinite amount of that liquid and therefore the egg would have infinite mass.

Such an egg would collapse into a black hole and we would not be able to continue in our observation.

In reality, in inert atmosphere, with overlapping stages:

- protein coagulation
- water boiling
- organic matter thermal dehydration
- general organic matter decomposion.
- carbon stage

If we kept temperature just above $\pu{100 ^\circ C}$ to keep boiling,  stage 3-4 would be very slow and we would not reach carbon.

Comment: That is a great scientific answer. In hindsight I should probably have worded the question a bit differently such as boiling away without coagulation, charring, etc. But you touched upon that as well. I think this is probably one of the better answers to a breakfast discussion I've had. I will leave the question unmarked for a few hours in case someone else wants to take a shot at producing a better answer.

Comment: Would it go through some nuclear burning stage or it would collapse directly into a black hole?

Comment: @Alchimista As it would already be inside in event horizon, together with the observer, both would already form the black hole, together with the rest of Universe. But I am definitely not an expert in GR and cosmology. :-D

Comment: I took it as infinite in mass but an egg :))

Comment: Being an egg and having infinite mass excludes each other. It may bypass a nuclear fusion and go directly to neutron star collapse and whatever is beyond that.

Answer (score -1):

While I agree some chemistry is involved in this operatory laboratorium experiment, I believe it may be a mere physics quest. Taking the theoretic existence of a blackhole into account, one can infer that this is a very hypothetical question. Scientists have discovered a way to test this finding in laboratoriums relating to physics.

Now.. it is essential to find a physics laboratory and ask questions for the laboratorium supervisors. An infinite mass of egg, such a computational integer exists not. Perhaps finding the forma for your hypothesis and simply taking the limit to infinity. The time and progress of an egg to boil indefinitely will be of answer to the equation. This will be an educated guess and a quite remarkable and extraordinary result.